# Vector of Objects that have vector of unique pointers

Tags: c++11, vector, visual-studio-2013, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

I have a vector ex:TestStructVec of objects for ex:TestStruct, where object contains a vector of unique pointers ex: uptrVec.

```
struct TestClass {};

struct TestStruct
{
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TestClass> > uptrVec;
}
std::vector<TestStruct> TestStructVec;


TestStruct ts1;
 ts1.uptrVec.emplace_back(std::make_unique<TestClass>());
```

Now, when emplace back this object to vector, only in vs2013 , c++11,  it fails with attempt to reference the deleted function (assuming its some copy const issue). I

```
TestStructVec.emplace_back(std::move(ts1));
```

Pls let me know where im doing it wrong.

NOTE: In VS2015, and Vs2017 it compiles Fine and no error is observed.

Any recommendation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a bug in VS2013, or incomplete support for C++11?

Comment: Im really not sure if its a bug or if i am missing something to add? So do u think its a bug.

Comment: Like I said, probably a bug or missing C++11 feature. We can't tell without a complete program. Also, does it really matter to you, if it compiles with newer MSVC versions?

Comment: yes it matters because we deliver libs for all msvc versions

Answer (score 0):

std::make_unique is only available from c++14 onwards

you can see it here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

in section Non-member functions > make_unique > version (in green) :

Comment: Thanks for that. but using new also fails with the same issue.